# Persister Login Without Navbar Flickering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm using ReactJS for my next project and am using JWT and storing it in LocalStorage for persistent login. The issue occurs whenever I refresh my website, the navbar flickers between auth links and guest links. Can anyone help with the flickering/flashing between states while using persistent login?

Comment: You could get and initialize the data from LocalStorage *before* you do `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I couldn't find a solution to it on my own. I'm making my first live project with react node and Mongo. Also, can you share the resource on how to initialize the data from localStorage before ReactDOM.render?